# Values from previous function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have some JavaScript code, calling Ajax:

```
function foo(e, e1, curc) {
    var sender = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
    var modal3 = document.getElementById('mymodal3');
    modal3.style.display = "block";
    var spin = 0;

    console.log("Code_I: ", e); ///<---- First log
    $('#mform9').submit(function (e2) {
        e2.preventDefault();
        e2.stopImmediatePropagation();

        spin = $('#spinner2').spinner("value");
        $('#spinner2').spinner("value", 0);

        console.log("Code: ", e);///<---- Second log
        document.getElementById("mform9").reset();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'script.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "id=" + e4 + "&mod=" + spin + "&curc=" + curc,
            success: function (data) 
            {
                modal3.style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("itog").innerHTML = data.d + data.a;
            },
            error: function (xhr) 
            {
                modal3.style.display = "none";

            }
        });
        return false;
    });

}
});

}
```

I call my function in HTML like this:

```
onclick="javascript:foo(7700000010032,1,140)"
```

In first call all is OK. But in second call,with different first value, I have new value here:

```
 console.log("Code_I: ", e); ///<---- First log
```

But here I have the value from previous function call:

```
console.log("Code: ", e);///<---- Second log
```

So, calling the fuction two times with different param I get 
First call: Code_I: 4820109927406 Code: 4820109927406. 
Second call: Code_I: 7622300813437 Code: 4820109927406
I can not understand what is wrong and why I have old values in my function.

Comment: Because in your second log you are capturing `e` from first call. What did you expect? Did you want the event data of submit event to be logged?

Comment: `e` is always the same in first and in second call, why do you expect it to be different?!

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you call `foo` once, you get two logs : "A" and "A". Then you call `foo` a second time with a different value, you expect "B" and "B". But actually you get "B" and "A"? Correct?

Comment: I simply need to call my script.php with different parameters each time user clicks button, that calls my function.

Comment: Jeremy Thille - yes. First call: Code_I:  4820109927406 Code:  4820109927406. Second call: Code_I:  7622300813437 Code:  4820109927406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happens because every time you call the `foo` function, you attach a new `.submit` handler to the form, creating a new scope each time. This is why you get the value of the first call after the second call.

Solution : Attach the `$('#mform9').submit` handler only once, outside of the `foo` function, like so :

```
let main // Initialize a variable outside of foo and submit, so you can access it from both

function foo(e, e1, curc) {
    // ...
    main = e
    console.log("Code_I: ", main )
    // ...
}

$('#mform9').submit(function (e2) {
    // ...
    console.log("Code: ", main )
    // ...
})
```

Comment: If this is not so hard - can you correct my code? I am new in JavaScript, i can not understand how to get $('#mform9').submit outside my function.

Comment: "let main" - is like a global variable in c++, as I understand. Thank you very much, it helps!